# Local port forwarding using iptables is not working

Tags: linux-mint, iptables, iptables-redirect

I am using the following command to forward incoming traffic from port 30 to port 1234. But it's not working. In Wireshark also there is no trace of packets directing to port 1234 are found.

sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 127.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 30 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1234.

Comment: Look at the kernel ip forwarding settings i.e. by running the command "sysctl -ar forward" Make sure that the relevant settings are enabled. For example, if you are using IP version 4, ensure that "net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding" is set to 1

Comment: Yes. net.ipv4.ip_forward is also set to 1 and also uncommented at the system variable file(/etc/sysctl.conf) to allow forwarding. But still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Local forwarding of packets different port doesn't pass through PREROUTING chain. They follow the OUTPUT chain. Changing the chain from PREROUTING to OUTPUT works.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 30 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1234
```

More details can be found here about the iptables NAT Filters:
https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial

Answer (score 0):

check if this is enabled or not by

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

If There are any entries , delete them using:

```
sudo iptables -F -t nat
```

Try without src dest flags:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1234
```

check again if this is enabled or not by

```
sudo iptables -t nat -L
```

It is Important to remove chained entries queued by default to "OUTPUT" route.